# Direct3D12 failed to call ClearRenderTargetView

Tags: c++, directx, directx-12

Source code: https://github.com/AinoMegumi/Direct3D12

I'm trying to init Direct3D12 Window.

In function Direct3D12::OnFrameRender (watch source code above, Direct3D12.cpp line 251),

```
    void Direct3D12::OnFrameRender() {
    this->CommandList->RSSetViewports(0, &this->ViewPort); 
    SetResourceBarrier(D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET);
    float ClearColor[4] = { static_cast<float>(0xff) / 255.0f, static_cast<float>(0xc0) / 255.0f, static_cast<float>(0xcb) / 255.0f, 1.0f };
    this->CommandList->ClearRenderTargetView(this->CPUDescriptorHandle, ClearColor, 0, nullptr); // ここで落ちてる
    SetResourceBarrier(D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT);
    this->Present(0);
}
```

Now, I tried to call ClearRenderTargetView. However, Unhandled exception was thrown from KernelBase.dll.

I investigate KernelBase.dll and detect who throw exception.

Watch this asm dump
https://pastebin.com/YBJLMBxE

The scenario is

1. on address 00007FF8E6380977 call
2. on address 00007FF8E6368AF2 syscall
3. JUMP TO ADDRESS 00007FF8E6380977!!!!
4. jump to address 00007FF8E6368AE0
5. on address 00007FF8E6368AF2 syscall,

The error message is

ハンドルされない例外が 0x00007FF8E27F3C58 (KernelBase.dll) で発生しました(Direct3D.exe 内): 0x0000087D (パラメーター: 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000028379BCE20, 0x0000021B7FD80FB0)。

What is a correct way to use ClearRenderTargetView and init window?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste the relevant code parts here. External links tend to die out or the target page content there may get modified preventing future question readers from figuring out what was that all about. Typically questions are required to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). it might be waste of time to paste all the usual DX boilerplate, but you should definitely include initialization parts and those functions called from the given snippet.

Comment: Did you Reset commands list (setting new allocator) prior to pushing commands [as shown on the snippet from MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn903900(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: You need to ``Reset`` the command list. See [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) for a complete basic game loop for DirectX 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct `RenderTargetView` call scenario is below

1. make `CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE` variable **for each time**
2. pass it to `OMSetRenderTargets`
3. call `ClearRenderTargetView`

https://github.com/AinoMegumi/Direct3D12/blob/eed1650b59aba61648e45758dc759a415dfb6b17/Direct3D/Direct3D12.cpp#L263-L266